# Buscar numero mayor de una Lista c#

Tags: c#

Buenas Noches,

Tengo que conseguir el numero mayor de una lista y no hayo como obtenerla, estoy usando 2 for para conseguirlo pero se me guarda el ultimo mayor no consigo como hacerlo.
Este es mi codigo:

```
static int get(int[] a)
    {
        int sort = 0;
        int sort2 = 0;
        int mayor = 0;
        List<int> a1 = new List<int>();
        foreach (int test in a)
        {
            a1.Add(test);
        }
        int cont = a1.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < cont; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < cont; k++)
            {
                sort = a1[i];
                sort2 = a1[k];
                if (sort > sort2)
                {
                    mayor = sort;
                }
                else
                {
                    mayor = sort2;
                }
            }

        }

        return mayor;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Buen día**

En caso que no sea necesario el `for` *que no sea un ejercicio usando ese ciclo* agrega `using System;` y `using System.Linq;` y usa el `Max`.

```
{
  List<int> a1 = new List<int>();
  /* Tu foreach donde llenas "a1" */

  return a1.Max();
}
```

Aquí lo puede ver mejor [Max y Min](https://www.dotnetperls.com/max)

Claro está en lo anterior falta validar si tiene datos

Comment: Oye muchas gracias, el FOR era lo unico que vi para hacerlo.
Intentare con el Min, Max
Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Listo,

El segundo for estaba de mas, solamente tenia que recorer una vez y guardar el mayor en mi variable de la siguiente forma

```
             int sort = 0;
       // int sort2 = 0;
        int mayor = 0;
        List<int> a1 = new List<int>();
        foreach (int test in a)
        {
            a1.Add(test);
        }
        int cont = a1.Count;
        //AQUI ESTA LA OPERACION DE HAYAR EL NUMERO MAYOR
        for (int i = 0; i < cont; i++)
        {
            sort = a1[i];

            if (mayor > sort)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                mayor = sort;
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine(mayor);

        return mayor;
```